# Angular 2: handle bootstrap failure in main.ts with an @Injectable() service

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to handle bootstrap failure in `main.ts` using a service of mine, which is a logger that logs to a remote API.

Is it possible to use services that are added as providers in the `AppModule` instead of `main.ts`?

For example, this is how I am trying to use it now (won't work because the `Logger` service depends on other services, and those other services depend on other services, and it just keeps going downward). This approach will not work.

Does anyone know of any other approaches, or is what I'm trying to do simply not possible?

Here's the example:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from 'environment';
import { hmrBootstrap} from './hmr';

import { Logger, HttpService } from 'core';
import { Log } from 'shared';

if (environment.production) {
    enableProdMode();
}

const bootstrap = () => platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    bootstrap()
        .then(success => {

        })
        .catch(err => {
            const logger = new Logger(); // Depends on HttpService...

            logger.logFatalToServer(new Log({...}));
        });
});
```